# Having an archive page with categories and tags

Tags: wordpress, tags, archive, categories

I'd like to have an archive (alternative to search) with Categories and Tags listed on one page. Is this possible? Can't seem to find any information on it.

Title/Archive Search<

Browse by category:
cat 1, cat 2 etc.

(Something more specific) Browse by Tags:
tag 1, tag 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
<div id="content" role="main">

    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php get_search_form(); ?>

    <h2>Browse by month:</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
    </ul>

    <h2>Browse by category:</h2>
    <ul>
         <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
    </ul>

    <h2>Browse by tags:</h2>
    <ul>
         <?php wp_tag_cloud(','); ?>
    </ul>

</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: How do I add this? I created a new php file and uploaded it to my home directory and also tried adding it to a page through wordpress. My home directory wasn't able to call my header (exactly as my calls from my other pages such as index.php)